# MATLAB: Initialize and empty table with headers and concatenate it to another table

Tags: matlab

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot concatenate the table variable 'epoch' because it is a cell
>   in one table and a non-cell in another.

To reproduce the error:

```
A.epoch = [1,2,3]';
A.value = [10,20,30]';
```

Initialized empty table with headers:

```
Aclean = cell2table(cell(1,2), 'VariableNames', {'epoch', 'value'});
```

Vertically concatenate the 2 tables:

```
Aclean = vertcat(Aclean, struct2table(A));
```

What is the best way of concatenating tables with a for loop in Matlab?

Comment: Can you please explain where it is that you want the for loop involved? Is it to add more columns(variables) or rows

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to initialize `Aclean` before a loop, then concatenate data to it in every loop iteration. If so, you can simply initialize `Aclean` to the empty array:

```
Aclean = [];

A.epoch = [1,2,3].';
A.value = [10,20,30].';
Aclean = vertcat(Aclean, struct2table(A));
```

However, if you know in advance how many rows you will add to the table, it is better to preallocate the full table:

```
% N = number of rows
A = array2table(zeros(N,2), 'VariableNames', {'epoch', 'value'});
A.epoch(1:3) = [1,2,3];
A.value(1:3) = [10,20,30];
```

It is cheaper to cut off unused rows from the bottom than to append in every iteration.

Yet another alternative is to work with a `struct` and convert it to a `table` after your loop. A struct is a built-in type, whereas a table is implemented as a custom class. The struct will therefore be more efficient to update.